# Jacobian criterion for projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $P\in Y=Z(f_{1},\cdots ,f_{s})$ be a projective variety. Then $Y$ is non singular at $P$ if and only if rank of the matrix $\Vert\partial f_{i}/x_{j}(P)\Vert=n-\dim{Y}$.

I know of the statement for affine varieties, and I am trying to prove it for projective varieties. This is what I have so far.

If $P\in \mathbb{P}^{n}$ then $P$ is in some open set $U_{i}=\{(a_{0},\cdots ,1,\cdots a_{n})\in\mathbb{P}^{n}\}$ where the $1$ appears in the $i^{th}$ spot. WLOG we may assume $i=0$ is this case. So $X\cap U_{0}$ is an affine variety. Defined by
$$X\cap U_{0}=Z(f_{1}(1,x_{1},\cdots x_{n}),\cdots ,f_{s}(1,x_{1},\cdots x_{n}))$$
Since this is affine we have that $X\cap U_{0}$ is nonsingular iff and only if the jacobian criterion is satisfied. I don't really see where to proceed from here since I don't know how the partials of the dehomoginzed polynomials compares to that of the homogeneous polynomials. Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Eulers Lemma for a homogeneous polynomial $f$, of degree $d$ 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_{i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}=df $$

Comment: That $df$ couldn't have been more misunderstandable :^)

Answer (score 5):

Consider the affine cone $C(Y)$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$; it is defined by the ideal$(f_1,\dots, f_r)$ of $k[x_0,\dots,k_{n+1}]$. Choose a point $Q$ of $C(Y)$ which is equivalent to the point of $Y$ in question. The affine Jacobi criterion applied to $C(Y)$ shows that $C(Y)$ is smooth at $Q$ if and only if the rank of the $r\times (n+1)$-Jacobi matrix $\Big(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}(Q)\Big)$, which may be replaced with the rank of  $\Big(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}(P)\Big)$, is $(n+1)-\dim C(Y)$. 
One can prove (i) $\dim C(Y)=\dim Y +1$, and (ii)$\dim T_Q(C(Y))=\dim T_P(Y)+1$; 
in particular, $Y$ is smooth at $P$ if and only if $C(Y)$ is smooth at $Q$. This implies the desired, projective Jacobi criterion. To prove (ii), one may assume $Q=(1,1,\dots,1)$ though an automorphism, and should show, using Linear Algebra, that the rank of the Jacobi matrix above does not decrese by removing
some (or eventually, any) column from the matrix.

Comment: There's a typo in line 1, k->x would fix it, but 'edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?' so you have to edit it.