# Proving singularity of a point in a projective variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ and $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}$ be the curve given by $x_{1}^{n} = x_{2}x_{0}^{n-1} - x_{2}^{n}$. I want to check whether $X$ is smooth or not.

In the case that you have a $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ and an algebraically closed field $k$ such that $\text{char}(k)$ does not divide $n$ and $n-1$, one can easily check that $X$ is indeed smooth. Here you can use the fact that $X = (X\cap D(x_{0}))\cup (X\cap D(x_{2}))$, where $D(x_{i}) = \{(x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2})\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\rvert x_{i}\neq 0\}$. One can use the isomorphisms

$\varphi_{0}: X\cap D(x_{0})\rightarrow Z(x_{0,1}^{n}-x_{0,2}+x_{0,2}^{n}), (x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2})\mapsto (\frac{x_{1}}{x_{0}},\frac{x_{2}}{x_{0}})$ and 
$\varphi_{2}: X\cap D(x_{2})\rightarrow Z(x_{2,1}^{n}-x_{2,0}^{n-1}+1), (x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2})\mapsto (\frac{x_{0}}{x_{2}},\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}})$,
where $x_{i,j} = \frac{x_{j}}{x_{i}}$.

For points $P\in X$ with $x_{2}=0$ we know that $x_{1}=0$ and consequently $x_{0} \neq 0$. Then we consider $\varphi_{0}$ and consequently we have the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, so $X$ is smooth at $P$.

For points $P\in X$ with $x_{2}\neq 0$ we can consider $\varphi_{2}$ and consequently we have the matrix \begin{pmatrix} -(n-1)x_{2,0}^{n-2} & nx_{2,1}^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}. By the assumption that $\text{char}(k)$ does not divide $n$ and $n-1$ one can find that the matrix is not equal to the zero matrix, so $X$ is smooth at $P$.

As soon as you have a $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ and an algebraically closed field $k$ such that $\text{char}(k)$ divides $n$ or $n-1$ the problems arrive. I also know that if $P\in X$ and $P$ lies on two irreducible components of $X$, then $P$ is singular.

**My Question/Problem:** How does one check if $X$ is smooth or not in the case that we have a $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ and an algebraically closed field $k$ such that $\text{char}(k)$ divides $n$ or $n-1$?

**Definition of Smoothness**: Let $X$ be a variety. For $P\in X$, $X$ is smooth at $P$ if there is an open subvariety $U$ of $X$ containing $P$ and an isomorphism $\varphi:U\rightarrow Z(f_{1},...,f_{n-d})\subset\mathbb{A}^{n}$ for some $d\leqslant n$ and $f_{1},...,f_{n-d}$, such that the rank of the $n-d$ by $n$ matrix over $k$:
$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}(\varphi(P)) \end{pmatrix}_{i,j}$ equals $n-d$, i.e. is maximal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done a very good job so far and are just a hair away from a complete solution. The only thing you need to do is use the fact that if $\operatorname{char} k$ divides $n$, then $n=0$ in $k$ (and similarly if $\operatorname{char} k$ divides $n-1$, then $n-1=0$ inside $k$). Once you do this and rewrite the Jacobian matrix after making these simplifications, you'll exactly see what you need to finish. I've provided full details in some spoiler tags below for you to check your work once you've done this.

> First, we note that we can upgrade our Jacobian to work directly with the homogeneous polynomial to avoid the need to split in to cases, as is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696922/jacobian-criterion-for-projective-varieties). Then our homogeneous Jacobian is given by the matrix $$J=\begin{pmatrix} (n-1)x_0^{n-2}x_2 & -nx_1^{n-1} & -nx_2^{n-1} \end{pmatrix}.$$

(spoiler text doesn't thread nicely without this linebreak)

> If $\operatorname{char} k$ divides $n$, then $n=0$ inside $k$, so $J = \begin{pmatrix} -x_0^{n-2}x_2 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ which has rank $0$ iff $x_0=0$ or $x_2=0$. We may verify that if $x_2=0$, this gives that $X$ is singular at $[1:0:0]$ and if $x_0=0$, at all points $[0:a:b]$ so that $a^n+b^n=0$. So $X$ is singular in this case.

(spoiler text doesn't thread nicely without this linebreak)

> If $\operatorname{char} k$ divides $n-1$, then $n-1=0$ inside $k$, so $J=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -x_1^{n-1} & -x_2^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$ which has rank $0$ iff $x_0=x_2=0$. There are no points with $x_0=x_2=0$ on $X$, though, so $X$ is smooth in this case.

**Edit**: In the comments, the asker revealed that their primary concern was with whether $X$ smooth at $P$ implies $\varphi_0(X\cap D(x_0))$ smooth at $\varphi_0(p)$. This is true: The intersection of $U$ and $X\cap D(x_0)$ may be covered by principal open affine subsets of the form $U_f=(X\cap D(x_0))_g$ for $f$ a function on $U$ and $g$ a function on $X\cap D(x_0)$, so there's one of these that contains $x$. If $\varphi(U)\cong V(f_1,\cdots,f_n)\subset \Bbb A^n$ then $\varphi(U)_f\cong V(f_1,\cdots,f_n,fx_{n+1}−1)\subset \Bbb A^{n+1}$ and we can see that the Jacobian matrix here is full rank on one side iff it's full rank on the other. Apply this again for $X\cap D(x_0)$ to get the result. (Put more succicntly, smoothness is a local condition.)

Comment: The only problem im left with is why for $P\in X\cap D(x_{0})$ we have $X$ is smooth at $P$ if and only if $\varphi_{0}(X\cap D(x_{0}))$ is smooth at $\varphi_{0}(P)$. I don't see how this follows from the definition of smoothness.

Comment: What? This is just the definition from the end of your post, which you already successfully applied twice in your post. Maybe I'm misunderstanding - could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Well, suppose that $P\in X$ such that $P\in D(x_{0})$. Now suppose that $X$ is smooth at $P$, then according to the definition there exists an open subvariety $U\subset X$ and an isomorphism $\varphi$ as described in the definition. It would be trivial if $U$ has to be equal to $X\cap D(x_{0})$ and $\varphi = \varphi_{0}$, but I don't see why this has to be the case.

Comment: It's an exist statement, not a uniqueness statement - all you need to do is verify that there is one such open subvariety and isomorphism, and $X\cap D(x_0)$ with $\varphi_0$ works.

Comment: Suppose that $\varphi_{0}(X\cap D(x_{0}))$ is smooth at $\varphi_{0}(P)$, then to prove that $X$ is smooth at $P$ we can indeed take $U:= X\cap D(x_{0})$ and $\varphi = \varphi_{0}$. The other implication is where my problem is, since here we assume that $X$ is smooth at $P$, and consequently from the definition of smoothness we find an opensubvariety $U\subset X$ and an isomorphism $\varphi$. From here I don't know how I can conclude that $\varphi_{0}(X\cap D(x_{0}))$ is smooth at $\varphi_{0}(P)$.

Comment: The intersection of $U$ and $X\cap D(x_0)$ may be covered by principal open affine subsets of the form $U_f=(X\cap D(x_0))_g$ for $f$ a function on $U$ and $g$ a function on $X\cap D(x_0)$, so there's one of these that contains $x$. If $\varphi(U)\cong V(f_1,\cdots,f_n)\subset \Bbb A^n $ then $\varphi(U)_f\cong V(f_1,\cdots,f_n, fx_{n+1}-1)\subset \Bbb A^{n+1}$ and we can see that the Jacobian matrix here is full rank on one side iff it's full rank on the other. Apply this again for $X\cap D(x_0)$ to get the result. (Put more succicntly, smoothness is a local condition.)